# Code signing certificate name

Tags: code-signing, signing

When purchasing a code signing certificate, do the CAs allow you to put anything for the signer name?

A few years ago I purchased a cert and they put it in my name, so when you launched the app it said the software was signed by Bart Tre.

I have a website now and I want to ask if it's possible to put it in the website name instead. Like, Bart Application Works.

For that to work, do I actually have to have that name registered as a real company or will they be able to do that for me?

Additionally, is it possible to omit the address in the certificate to get a little bit of privacy?

Comment: When getting an EV cert for one of my sites, I was advised by my cert issuer that it had to be the name of the company (and verifiable by their process - I assume State records or similar).

Comment: That's SSL though, not code signing, I think the process is different here.

Comment: 'Display your name or your company’s name, instead of “Unidentified Publisher,” during download and installation, so customers know you’re a legitimate developer.'
https://www.godaddy.com/ssl/code-signing-certificate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**The certificate shall indicate the approved identity**. If you are an individual, it will be your name. Otherwise, your company name.

That said, **the certificate does not necessarily indicate physical address or phone number**. It may be associated with an email address. You just need to prove that this email address is yours.

Most certificate providers only work with companies. For my part, I bought a certificate individually (in my own name) from [KSoftware](http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/).